# SQL Server - Returning Multiple Rows Based on 'IF' Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

with a better explanation:

I'm working in SQL server joining tables that that have multiple rows for each entity - or 'House' in my example data. I want only those 'House UIDs' that have a type of Garden, Drive and Entrance hall in the table I'm joining to. It doesn't matter if they have more than that, but there must be House_UID rows with at least Garden, Drive and Entrance hall as a 'Thing type' value for the House_UID to be returned.

In the example data this would be 1 and 3.

I've tried

```
Select HOUSE_UID, THING_TYPE from HOUSES

Join HOUSE_THINGS on HOUSES.HOUSE_THING = HOUSE_THINGS.THING

WHERE HOUSE_UID in (select HOUSE_UID from houses 
                    Join HOUSE_THINGS on HOUSES.HOUSE_THING = HOUSE_THINGS.THING
                   where house_thing = x)
   and HOUSE_UID in (select HOUSE_UID from houses 
                    Join HOUSE_THINGS on HOUSES.HOUSE_THING = HOUSE_THINGS.THING
                   where house_thing = y)

   and HOUSE_UID in (select HOUSE_UID from houses 
                    Join HOUSE_THINGS on HOUSES.HOUSE_THING = HOUSE_THINGS.THING
                   where house_thing = z)
```

but this doesn't seem to work - I'm getting results that don't have rows for everything I'm interested in. Any new ideas welcome!

Thanks

[image: Example Data]

Comment: "a large table in SQL server that has multiple rows for each entity" - ...so the data is denormalized?

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING etc

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Dai no the data is normalized

Comment: This is known as [Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), and there are a few different techniques available depending on your exact requirements. See also [High Performance Relational Division in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/#:~:text=Relational%20division%20is%20used%20in,before%20applying%20the%20final%20logic.)

Comment: thanks @Gareth , all of the relational division solutions I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregation

```
select houseid from table_name
where house in ('Garden', 'Drive','Entrance hall')
group by houseid
having count(distinct house)>=3
```